# Ошибка в Jommla 3.8.2(Joomshopping) - Unknown column 'product_ean' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla3

Всем доброго времени суток! Проблема в админ-панели Joomla. Не могу удалить товар в joomshopping (версия 4.15.1), выдает ошибку:Unknown column 'product_ean' in 'where clause'

Как эту ошибку можно исправить?